# Can you interpret "Waltz for Venus" differently?

Tags: phrases, meaning

I think you can have two interpretations for this. One being, a dance or music. Two being, accomplish something with little to no effort. Are these two interpretations correct or is it just the former that's correct?

Comment: Accomplishing something with little to no effort is not conveyed in that phrase. If it is, then it's an idiom I'm not familiar with.

Comment: ... Are you sure you don't mean something like "Winning at Wimbledon was a waltz for Venus"?... "Venus" in this case referring to Venus Williams, the tennis player? Because "was a waltz" does definitely mean "it was easy".

Comment: @Catija No it refers to a planet literally. It was an episode title in an anime i was watching. So is it correct to interpret as other meanings instead of "dance style" or "music"?

Comment: @3512331 If you're talking about *Cowboy Bebop*, yes, it means only the musical piece. Most if not all of the episode titles contain a type of music or at the very least a reference to music of some sort, "Asteroid Blues", "Heavy Metal Queen", "Jupiter Jazz". As far as I know, there's no double meaning here. And, even if there were, it would be ironic, as nothing in the show is a "waltz" for the characters. You might consider posting this on [Anime](http://anime.stackexchange.com/), as they're sure to have people interested in thinking about the depth of meaning in *Bebop* titles :D

Comment: Also, you should include contextual info such as "it's the episode title of an anime" as part of your questions in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The word "waltz" most definitely has two meanings.

A "[waltz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waltz_%28music%29)" is a particular type of music usually with 3/4 time and the dance that's done along to it:

> A waltz (German: Walzer; French: Valse, Italian: Valzer, Spanish: Vals, Polish: Walc), probably deriving from German Ländler, is dance music in triple meter, and if written, often written in time signature 3/4. A waltz typically sounds one chord per measure, and the accompaniment style particularly associated with the waltz is (as seen in the example to the right) to play the root of the chord on the first beat, the upper notes on the second and third beats.

In addition, the phrase "was a waltz" or "waltzed through something" means that it was [easy or simple](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/waltz):

> n. an easy task. *The job was a waltz. We did it in a day.*
>    in. to get through something easily. *I waltzed through my comps and started on my research in my second year.*

"Venus" has nothing to do with this use, though.

---

In relation to *[Cowboy Bebop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_Bebop)*, the show is highly influenced by music. It's part of the show title ([bebop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bebop)) and the titles of the individual [episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Cowboy_Bebop_episodes). Yoko Kanno's score is also a hugely important part of the show.

I don't think that the double meaning of the musical style and "easy" are necessarily intentionally used here. One of the main themes of the show is that the main characters are constantly struggling, so I'm not sure how "easy" ties into that.

That being said, some of the titles certainly have multiple meanings. For example, episode 9 "Jamming with Edward" - "jamming" means both "[signal jamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_jamming)" and "[playing music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam_session)" - which certainly coincides with the theme of the episode.